# Is the following AES key a vulnerability?

Tags: java, android, security, aes

I am searching the source code of an application. I wanted to check whether there is any hardcoded key inside in it,so I have searched for keyword. I found the followings:

```
package com.igen.configlib.constant;
public class Constant{
    public static final String AES_KEY="1111111111111111";
    public static final String AES_KEY_PRE=""214028";
    public static final String AES_VECTOR="1111111111111111";
    ...
    
}
```

Can the foregoing information be seen as vulnerability such as hardcoded key vulnerability ,or it is something irrelevant  ?

I am new in mobile and java, so can you explain what do they mean

They are used in:

```
.....

public static byte[] encrypt4CBC128ByDeviceSN(String str, String str2){
    String formatKeyAndVector=formayKeyAndVector(str2);
    return encrypt4CBC128(str, formatKeyandVector,formatKeyandVector)
}
public static byte[] encrypt4CBC128(String str){
    return encrypt4CBC128(str,"1111111111111111","1111111111111111")
}

....

 public static byte[] decrypt4CBC128ByDeviceSN(byte[] bArr, String str){
    String formatKeyAndVector=formayKeyAndVector(str);
    return decrypt4CBC128(str, formatKeyandVector,formatKeyandVector)
}
public static byte[] decrypt4CBC128(byte[] bArr){
    return decrypt4CBC128(bArr,"1111111111111111","1111111111111111")
}

....
```

Comment: In general hard coded keys are bad, but it depends on what you do with the keys. AES can be used of deobfuscation of resources or you can use it to generate a MAC. So you should track where the key is used and what data is en- or decrypted with it.

Comment: It certainly is now, because you leaked it. This is what keystores are for.

Comment: @user207421 hımm, i confused now. According to the answer of Andreas Lundgren ,it is not. When ı read the java code, i think it is used in AES but not sure because of i am not a java expert.Moreover, it became me suspicious that why they used $111.111$ instead of using random key such as $A14#e%...$

Answer (score 1):

ASE (Advanced Encryption Standard) is a symmetric cipher, that is there is only one key and that is supposed to be secret. It's used both for encryption and decryption. A third party that obtains your key can thus decipher your messages. **For that reason, yes, it's a vulnerability if leaked.**

This should never be stored as code in any central cvs, only is dedicated secret storages. In practise though, **before you raise a red alert**, it could be that this specific key is used for some test environment or local development, and in reality causes no harm if leaked. It's not uncommon although still bad practise because of false positive that make searches like yours (or similar provided by github, gitlab, etc) hard to use and trust.

Comment: hımm, when i look at the foregoing source code, i became suspicious. So, there is no vulnerability here